# Vim macro: Incrementing numbers on non-consecutive lines

Tags: vim, macros, yaml

I'm working with a YAML file that has an integer as ID which appears every 4-6 lines.  I'm looking to add a record in the middle of this file (for readability) that keeps the sequential numbering intact.

File format below.  Any ideas?

```
- id: 1
  type: string
  option: diff_string
  other: alt_string   // note: 'other' option does not appear for all records

- id: 2
  type: string
  option: diff_string

//new record would go here as id: 3, increasing id: # of all following records by 1

- id: 3
  type: string
  option: diff_string
  other: alt_string
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you can achieve what you want with setting a counter (here: variable `g:I`) to 1:

```
let g:I=1
```

And then execute a substitution on each line that matches `^- id: \d\+$`:

```
%g/^- id: \d\+$/ s/\d\+/\=g:I/|let g:I=g:I+1
```

The substition uses the `\=` thingy (see `:help sub-replace-expression`) to substitue `\d\+` with the actual value of `g:I`. After the substition, the counter is incremented (`let g:I=g:I+1`).

With the `g/^- id: \d\+$/` you ensure that the substition is only performed on lines matching `^- id: \d\+`.

**Edit** If you want to have a *map* for it, you can place the following snippet into your *.vimrc*:

```
nnoremap resync :let g:I=1<CR>:%g/^- id: \d\+$/ s/\d\+/\=g:I/\|let g:I=g:I+1<CR>
```

which allows to *resync* your ids by typing `resync` in *normal mode*.

Note the escaping of the `|` with the `\` and the use of `<CR>` where you would press enter.

Comment: This is another valid way, and it will renumber every single ID in the document starting with 1 from the start to the end. Copy this code into your clipboard and use `:@+` to try (if you use GUI).

Comment: What does `:@+` do? I see it prints the `id: x` lines but I have no idea as to why that is.

Comment: Nyfenegger: `:@` plays Ex commands stored in a register. The `+` register is normally connected to the external clipboard. See `:help :@`. This is damn useful if you want to try excerpts from vimrc: `yy` then `:@"`.

Comment: I like this method as it makes sure entire file is in order, regardless of starting point.  Thank you!

Comment: René: Is it possible to save this as a bind in .vimrc?  When I tried, I'm getting errors due to the variables.

Comment: @René Nyfenegger: I would prefer « nnoremap » rather than « nmap » unless you've a good reason to use « nmap »!

Comment: @Benoit: Thanks, it's changed.

Answer (score 3):

in order to increment all subsequent ids from cursor line + 1:

```
:.+1,$g/^- id: \d\+$/exec 'normal! 0' . nr2char(1)
```

(`nr2char(1)` is like keying CTRL-A in).

You can also do:

```
:.+1,$g/^- id: \d\+$/normal! 0^A
```

Where you enter `^A` typing CTRL-V then CTRL-A. Note that I prefer the first version: you can copy-paste it around, there is no literal control character in the code.

Detail:

- `.+1,$` is the range from next line till end of file. `:help range`.
- `:g` command operates on all lines obeying to a pattern. The opposite is `:v`. `:help :g`
- `/^- id: \d\+$/` matches `- id:` at the start of a line, followed by 1 or more digits and then end of line (`:help pattern`)
- `:normal!` plays normal commands: 0 to go to start of line, CTRL-A to increment next number.

If you want a mapping:

```
nnoremap <F1> :.+1,$g/^- id: \d\+$/exec 'normal! 0' . nr2char(1)<enter>
```

Put that in your vimrc, and now enjoy pressing F1 in normal mode, and watch all ids below cursor line incrementing.

Comment: Excellent, though I prefer the global change personally.  Thank you, Benoit, for your help across all answers with this question.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following short and straightforward substitution command.

```
:,$s/^- id: \zs\d\+/\=submatch(0)+1/
```